# Print page in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm looking for a print page using `vue`. I have had a look a `vue-html-to-paper` which at first I thought was awesome but, and it's a big one, I don't want the page enlarging when clicking the button and then going back to normal once the print window closed as this package does. Makes the site look ugly. If it didn't do that I'd be all over it.

It needs to also include `Boostrap` `CSS` and my own `CSS`.

Anyone got any ideas please as I'm running out of options here.

Or is there a way to stop the `vue-html-to-paper` enlarging the page?

I am NOT using `Boostrap-Vue`

Comment: use a print stylesheet which alters the dom styling [`@media print`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media), then just use a print page js call [`window.print();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print)

Comment: its not that big 72 lines.. https://github.com/mycurelabs/vue-html-to-paper/blob/master/src/index.js

Comment: maybe you can manually use window.open and window.write feature to do it?